# How can I normalize a dict inside a CSV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a CSV file which contains a dict value.

```
Test.CSV

id,name,contact,Location
1,Julie,"[{""name"":""Jenny Brown"",""relation"":""mother"",""number"":2113131313},{""name"":""Jorge"",""relation"":""brother"",""number"":121313131}]",US
2,Jim,"[{""name"":""Sana"",""relation"":""sister"",""number"":83279131}]",UK
```

I want to normalize this CSV. Expected output:

```
id , name, contact_name,contact_realation,contact_number,location
1,Julie,Jenny Brown,mother,2113131313,US
1,Julie,Jorge,brother,121313131,US
2,Jim,Sana,sister,83279131,UK
```

I have loaded the data using CSV reader but I am not able to normalize the contact value. How can I do that?

```
csvfile = csv.reader(open(filename, encoding="utf8"))
```

So far I tried this:

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename, converters={'contact':json.loads}, header=0)
contact_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df['contact'])
```

but getting the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Parse the json block for each line then assemble your new line from the attributes of interest.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but getting errors:
df=pd.read_csv(filename, converters={'contact':json.loads}, header=0)
contact_df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(df['contact'])

Comment: Add what you've tried to the question along with how it failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `pd.io.json.json_normalize` is used to work with `JSON` objects directly. But it seems you want to work with `pd.Series` directly. A nice trick is to map the value to a `Series` or `Dataframe`. Then you can use `concat` to create the contact dataframe, with mutliple index. Finally, you merger it back to the original dataframe.

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename, converters={'contact':json.loads}, header=0)
df.index.name = 'row_id'
concat_df = df.merge(
    pd.concat(df["contact"].apply(pd.DataFrame).tolist(), keys=df.index),
    left_index=True, right_index=True
).drop("contact",1)
```

Output:

```
          id name_x Location       name_y relation      number     role
row_id                                                                 
0      0   1  Julie       US  Jenny Brown   mother  2113131313      NaN
       1   1  Julie       US        Jorge      NaN   121313131  brother
1      0   2    Jim       UK         Sana   sister    83279131      NaN
```

Comment: I think because of pd.Series(x[0]) it is only serialize the first value of id 1

Comment: no, the `apply` runs on all the ids. Note that each row has a `list`, and you are interested in the first element in the list for each row, now?

Comment: the output shows
 ```
 id   name Location         name relation      number
0   1  Julie       US  Jenny Brown   mother  2113131313
1   2    Jim       UK         Sana   sister    83279131
```
but there should be three lines in output

Comment: ah sorry. so you want to split rows. didn't get that. i'll revise

Comment: yes as for one person there could be multiple contact like father,mother

Comment: Changed it to split the rows. Note that in your input, there is somethimes `role` and sometimes `relation`.

Comment: my bad, it should be relation. Thanks a lot. thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to do this with only the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), you can use something like this:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO
import json

data = """id,name,contact,location
1,Julie,"[{""name"":""Jenny Brown"",""relation"":""mother"",""number"":2113131313},{""name"":""Jorge"",""relation"":""brother"",""number"":121313131}]",US
2,Jim,"[{""name"":""Sana"",""relation"":""sister"",""number"":83279131}]",UK
3,Alice,,UK"""

reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO(data))
with open("processed.csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=["id","name","contact_name","contact_relation","contact_number","location"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        new_row = {k:row[k] for k in row if k != "contact"}
        if row["contact"]:
            contacts = json.loads(row["contact"])
            for contact in contacts:
                for key in contact:
                    new_row["contact_" + key] = contact[key]
                writer.writerow(new_row)
        else:
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Which results in:

```
$cat processed.csv
id,name,contact_name,contact_relation,contact_number,location
1,Julie,Jenny Brown,mother,2113131313,US
1,Julie,Jorge,brother,121313131,US
2,Jim,Sana,sister,83279131,UK
3,Alice,,,,UK
```

---

Edit: Updated code to account for entries with no contact info.

Comment: If for any entry there is no contact info the code gives error.

Comment: Right @SaNa3819, I did not account for this possibility. I updated the code to fix this.